# remove text from textfield if checkbox is selected

Tags: jquery

I have 2 radiobuttons (A,B) acting as shipping options and one input textfield for inputting phone numbers. 
After selecting A, I need to show custom help text inside the text area ('phone required'). If button B is selected - there should be no help text.

If A is selected, helptext should be removed after user clicks inside textfield and types the number. 
If any option is selected and the textfield is filled. It should stay this way.

My code works except the help text is not removed if user selects A option and after B option without typing anything.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('input#edit-quote-option-flatrate-3---0').change(function () {
    if ($('input#edit-quote-option-flatrate-3---0').is(":checked")) {


  $('.default').each(function () {
    var defaultVal = ('tel');
    $(this).focus(function () {
      if ($(this).val() == defaultVal) {
        $(this).removeClass('active').val('');
      }
    })
      .blur(function () {
      if ($(this).val() == '') {
        $(this).addClass('active').val(defaultVal);
      }
    })
      .blur().addClass('active');
  });
    } else {

        $('.default').removeClass('active').val('');

    }
  });
});
```

full code is here http://jsfiddle.net/NKcFs/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a change handler for the second option that sets the value to blank... thats what you wanted to do, right?

```
   $('#edit-quote-option-flatrate-3---1').change(function(){  
    $('.default').each(function () {
      if($(this).val() == 'tel'){ // if the user didn't change it, clear the field
          $(this).val('');
      }
    });
  });
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/gcmDu/1/

Comment: I edited the code and the fiddle to only clear the field if the user hasn't edited it

Comment: if some text is already input in textfield, it should not be removed if user changes any option. I should be more clear in my question sorry

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
$('.a').click(function () {
    var t = $('textarea');
    if (!t.val()) t.val('phone required');
    t.focus(function () {
       if (this.value == 'phone required') this.value = '';
    });
    t.blur(function () {
       if (!this.value) this.value = 'phone required';
    });
    $('.b').removeAttr('checked');
});
$('.b').click(function () {
    var t = $('textarea');
    if (!t.val() || t.val() == 'phone required') t.val('');
    $('.a').removeAttr('checked');
});
```

Working jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6ULG5/5).

Comment: this clears inputted text after accidentaly hitting A option again. If A is selefted and B is clicked, help text does not dissapear. I am using chrome

Comment: @Jamie  Seems like you fixed it.  You could have put in your comment that you fixed it, please try again.  It's a little shady acting like it worked all along.

Comment: @Boundless "Should be working now" indicates that, _right now_ (i.e. after adjustments), it's working.

Comment: @Jamie I am referring to this comment: 'Working fine for me. What error do you think you're seeing?'... and you posted that after changing the fiddle.  I can tell by the fiddle url

Comment: @Jamie this works good as code by Boundless. Now I have no idea which code shoud I use:)

Answer (score 0):

The change event is not fired when a specific radio button is deselected.  The simplest way to make this work would be to change the selector for the change event to:

```
$('input[name="quote-option"]').change(function () { ... });
```

This adds the change events to all radio buttons sharing the name "quote-option", and thus will fire when B is selected as well.

Additionally, you need to unbind the events you bind when the A option is selected.  So when you select option B, do this:

```
$('.default').unbind('blur').unbind('focus');
```

Updated jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NKcFs/11/).

Comment: If text is already input and user changes to option B, the code clears the text which is undesirable.

Comment: Just check for default values when B is selected like you do on blur.  Updated jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NKcFs/13/).  You will most likely want to refactor this as well to bind a blur/focus event to the field no matter what and use the proper behavior for the currently selected option.  Binding and unbinding the blur/focus events based on coditions like this may lead to error-prone code.

Comment: Something along the lines of [this](http://jsfiddle.net/NKcFs/20/).  It removes the binding on focus in the original code (which causes a potential bug if you enter text while B is selected, then select A and clear the field), and it keeps the logic in very clearly defined sections so it's easy to see what's happening.  This is just an example, and I'm sure there are many other ways to clean it up a bit.